# Extension is not having new admin url in link (redirect to dashboard)

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, ce-1.9.0.1, backend

I set my new backend URL to an unknown url. Everything works except one link in the admin menu to change my front-end banners (images on the homepage) Banner7 from Magentothem is managing this.

When I got to the link in the code it is for the Banner7 extension manage items part:

`http://www.thefixedgearshop.com/index.php/banner7/adminhtml_banner7/index/key/SECRETKEY/`

For other extensions it included my admin url in it like this:

`http://www.thefixedgearshop.com/index.php/{ADMINURL}/system_config/edit/section/prozoom/key/SECRETKEY/`

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me out asap.

My config file of banner7 extension looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentothem_Banner7>
            <version>1.8.0.0</version>
        </Magentothem_Banner7>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <banner7>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentothem_Banner7</module>
                    <frontName>banner7</frontName>
                </args>
            </banner7>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <banner7>
                    <file>banner7.xml</file>
                </banner7>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <banner7>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentothem_Banner7</module>
                    <frontName>banner7</frontName>
                </args>
            </banner7>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <magentothem translate="title" module="banner7">
                <title>Magentothem</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <banner7 translate="title" module="banner7">
                        <title>Banner7</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <items translate="title" module="banner7">
                                <title>Manage Items</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                <action>banner7/adminhtml_banner7</action>
                            </items>
                            <configuration>
                                <title>Configuration</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/banner7</action>
                            </configuration>
                        </children>
                    </banner7>
                </children>
            </magentothem>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Magentothem_Banner7>
                            <title>Banner7 Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Magentothem_Banner7>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <banner7>
                    <file>banner7.xml</file>
                </banner7>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <banner7>
                <class>Magentothem_Banner7_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>banner7_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </banner7>
            <banner7_mysql4>
                <class>Magentothem_Banner7_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <banner7>
                        <table>banner7</table>
                    </banner7>
                </entities>
            </banner7_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <banner7_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Magentothem_Banner7</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </banner7_setup>
            <banner7_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </banner7_write>
            <banner7_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </banner7_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <banner7>
                <class>Magentothem_Banner7_Block</class>
            </banner7>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <banner7>
                <class>Magentothem_Banner7_Helper</class>
            </banner7>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
        <banner7>
            <banner7_config>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <animation>boxRainReverse</animation>
                <speed>5000</speed>
                <interval>600</interval>
                <qty_item>5</qty_item>
                <description>0</description>
                <next_back>1</next_back>
                <nav_ctrl>0</nav_ctrl>
            </banner7_config>
        </banner7>
    </default>
</config>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `<menu>` element in either system.xml or adminhtml.xml

The `<action>` url should start with `adminhtml/` and NOT `banner7/adminhtml_banner7`

E.g.

```
<action>adminhtml/[other/urlhere]</action>
```

Review your config.xml

Change

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <namespace>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Company_NameSpace</module>
                <frontName>adminorderconfirmation_admin</frontName>
            </args>
        </namespace>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

To

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company_NameSpace before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_NameSpace[_Adminhtml]</Company_NameSpace>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>    
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: This doesn't make a difference or solve anything. Keeps going to the same dashboard. Action in the config.xml page is: `<items translate="title" module="banner7">
                                <title>Manage Items</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                <action>banner7/adminhtml_banner7</action>
                            </items>`

Comment: Can you add the part to your controller and add your config.xml to your question

Comment: This is the url where it goes to when I click link: `http://www.thefixedgearshop.com/index.php/banner7/adminhtml_banner7/index/key/S‌​ECREYKEY/`

Comment: You need to change your admin route (`<admin>
        <routers>`) and flush cache if need